# Do quays affect land value

Tags: cities-skylines

The 1.4 patch introduced, amongst other things, quays.

Do quays affect the land value compared to leaving it as a beach? I.e if I have a few houses close to the shore, but I transform the shore to quays, will the land value increase/decrease or remain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a few months late, but I've tested this a couple of times in different situations. I found out that it does not affect the land value directly. However, there are a few certain situations that you can use them for.

1. Using Quays help you get slightly closer to the water allowing a slightly higher yield when zoning due to elevation.
2. Slightly lesser risk of a random flood destroying the houses/buildings.
3. And finally, depending on opinion, it could make the city look better, while not effecting any value(such as entertainment/pollution ect.)